# Is there a place to buy Esperanto merchandise?

Tags: culture

I would like to buy some Esperanto stickers for my laptop and maybe even some t-shirts and a mug. Is there a place to buy this sort of thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [La Sekreta Societo de Esperantistoj](http://cxemizoj.com/). They specialize in T-shirts and stickers. I have their stickers on my laptop and my car.

You can also order supplies from the Esperanto USA [bookstore](http://www.esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/), the EAB [bookstore](http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/bookcat.htm), or the UEA [bookstore](http://katalogo.uea.org/).

Additionally, [Cafe Press](http://www.cafepress.com/+esperanto+gifts), [Red Bubble](http://www.redbubble.com/shop/esperanto), and other online shops are known to carry Esperanto merchandise as well.

Comment: Sweet. I hadn't heard of this before. Nice!

Comment: Yeah, I love La Sekreta Societo de Esperantistoj. :)

Comment: They have a twitter and a FB too: https://twitter.com/cxemizoj , https://www.facebook.com/cxemizoj

Answer (score 5):

Look up CafePress and go to their website.  When you get to the main page, search for Esperanto.  There are quite a few shirts, mugs, stickers, and such sold there.

Link: http://www.cafepress.com/+esperanto+gifts

Answer (score 4):

Your national Esperanto organisation is probably the best place to look.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen such merchandise being sold at bookshops at international Esperanto events, e.g. at IJK and UK.

Answer (score 1):

RedBubble sells many esperanto things including t-shirts:

https://www.redbubble.com/shop/?query=esperanto